# Side By Side Camera using two SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview

I have written the code for an android app that should show Camera preview side by side on two surface views simultaneously.

**This is the output I wanted :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBk3z.jpg

**The Issue I am facing :**

1) When the apk is installed two apps are installed.

2)First app shows the camera preview on the right surfaceview.

3)Second app shows the camera preview on the left surfaceview

Screenshots :

**1) Single APK Installs two apps :**

Link to screenshot showing the error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKw2b.png

**2) When I open First App shows Camera Preview on the Left SurfaceView :**

Link to screenshot showing the error : i.stack.imgur.com/LqA5j.png

**3) When I open Second app shows Camera Preview on the Right SurfaceView :**

Link to screenshot showing the error : i.stack.imgur.com/DU6c7.png

**Code :**

**Android Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.javacodegeeks.androidsurfaceviewexample.AndroidSurfaceviewExample"

        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.javacodegeeks.androidsurfaceviewexample.AndroidSurfaceviewExample2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    </activity>
</application>
```

**First Java Class :**

```
Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

PictureCallback rawCallback;
ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
PictureCallback jpegCallback;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0


    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000).show();
            refreshCamera();
        }
    };
}

public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
    //take the picture
    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
}

public void refreshCamera() {
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    refreshCamera();
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        // open the camera
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
    Camera.Parameters param;
    param = camera.getParameters();

    // modify parameter
    param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
    camera.setParameters(param);
    try {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
        // the preview.
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // stop preview and release camera
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
```

**Second Class :**

```
Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView2;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder2;

PictureCallback rawCallback;
ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
PictureCallback jpegCallback;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    surfaceView2 = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView2);
    surfaceHolder2 = surfaceView2.getHolder();

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    surfaceHolder2.addCallback(this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0


    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000).show();
            refreshCamera();
        }
    };
}

public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
    //take the picture
    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
}

public void refreshCamera() {
    if (surfaceHolder2.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder2);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    refreshCamera();
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        // open the camera
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
    Camera.Parameters param;
    param = camera.getParameters();

    // modify parameter
    param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
    camera.setParameters(param);
    try {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
        // the preview.
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder2);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // stop preview and release camera
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
```

**activity_main.xml :**

```
    <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
    <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Important Update :**

I figured out that by editing the AndroidManifest.xml file and by deleting that the second activity is launcher we can get rid of the two app icons in the homescreen.

But the apk generated by doing so on installation opens up by showing the camera preview on just the left surfaceview and the right surface view appears black,

Thank you , Hope you guys can help me out :)

Comment: I'm on a similar quest. Why did you decide to make 2 classes? Have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: Hey @Geeve George and Niels...you both Achived this...if yes then Please help me out...i also want multiple camera preview into single activity....i already asked a Question Here..Please check and tell me if you know its an urgent......PLEASE....my question Link is.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/how-to-apply-custom-filters-in-a-camera-surfaceview-preview